# Sum of 1+3+5...+n until the sum exceeds 100

Tags: python, algorithm, math, sum

Then the sum and the last added number and the number of numbers added must be printed.

I am currently stuck, I managed to get the sum part working. The last added number output is printed `"23"` but should be `"21"`. And lastly, how can I print the number of numbers added?

Output goal: `121, 21, 11`

Here is my code:

```
n = int()
sum = 0
k = 1
while sum <= 100:
  if k%2==1:
    sum = sum + k
  k = k + 2
print('Sum is:', sum)
print("last number:", k)
```

Edit: Would like to thank everyone for their help and answers!

Comment: `k` was the first number _over_ 100. You need to go back by 2.

Comment: Don't use `sum` for a variable name in general. There is a built-in function by that name

Comment: By the time you're checking that `sum <= 100`, you've already added in the `23` and assign it to your `k`.

Comment: The `k%2==1` is redundant if you're already doing `+=2`

Comment: 1) It is not a good idea to use default words like "sum" for variables, better call it something else.
2)The k for the next iteration is calculated at the end of the loop, so the k you get at the end is the one you would use in the next iteration (that doesn't happen because the loop condition happens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that (you can *prove* it by *induction*)

```
1 + 3 + 5 + ... + 2 * n - 1 == n**2
<-----    n items    ----->
```

So far so good in order to get `n` all you have to do is to compute *square root*:

```
n = sqrt(sum)
```

in case of `100` we can find `n` when `sum` reach `100` as

```
n = sqrt(100) == 10
```

So when `n == 10` then `sum == 100`, when `n = 11` (last item is `2 * n - 1 == 2 * 11 - 1 == 21`) the `sum` exceeds `100`: it will be

```
n*n == 11 ** 2 == 121
```

In general case

```
n = floor(sqrt(sum)) + 1
```

**Code:**

```
def solve(s):
    n = round(s ** 0.5 - 0.5) + 1;
    
    print ('Number of numbers added: ', n);
    print ('Last number:             ', 2 * n - 1)
    print ('Sum of numbers:          ', n * n)
    
solve(100)
```

We have no need in loops here and can have `O(1)` time and space complexity solution (please, [fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/DS6YIhc))

More demos:

```
test : count : last : sum
-------------------------
  99 :    10 :   19 : 100
 100 :    11 :   21 : 121
 101 :    11 :   21 : 121
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the curiosity to try a few partial sums, you immediately recognize the sequence of perfect squares. Hence, there are 11 terms and the last number is 21.

```
print(121, 21, 11)
```

---

More seriously:

```
i, s= 1, 1
while s <= 100:
    i+= 2
    s+= i

print(s, i, (i + 1) // 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `while` loop so that you test and `break` before the top:

```
k=1
acc=0
while True:
  if acc+k>100:
    break
  else:
    acc+=k
    k+=2

>>> k
21
>>> acc 
100
```

And if you want the accumulator to be `121` just add `k` before you break:

```
k=1
acc=0
while True:
  if acc+k>100:
    acc+=k
    break
  else:
    acc+=k
    k+=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
k = k + 2
```

say

```
if (sum <= 100):
  k = k +2
```

...because that is, after all, the circumstance under which you want to add 2.

To also count the numbers, have another counter, perhasp `howManyNumbers`, which starts and 0 and you add 1 every time you add a number.

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply Change you code to,

```
n = int()
sum = 0
k = 1  
cnt = 0
while sum <= 100:
  if k%2==1:
    sum = sum + k
  k = k + 2
  cnt+=1
print('Sum is:', sum)
print("last number:", k-2)
print('Number of Numbers Added:', cnt)
```

Here, is the reason,
the counter should be starting from 0 and the answer of the last printed number should be k-2 because when the sum exceeds 100 it'll also increment the value of k by 2 and after that the loop will be falls in false condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can even solve it for the general case:

```
def sum_n(n, k=3, s =1):
    if s + k > n:
        print('Sum is', s + k)
        print('Last number', k)
        return
    sum_n(n, k + 2, s + k)
sum_n(int(input()))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
from itertools import count

total = 0
for i, num in enumerate(count(1, step=2)):
    total += num
    if total > 100:
        break

print('Sum is:', total)
print("last number:", 2*i + 1)
```

To avoid the update on `k`, you can also use the follwoing idiom

```
while True:
    total += k  # do not shadow built-in sum
    if total > 100:
        break
```

Or in Python >= 3.8:

```
while (total := total + k) <= 100:
    k += 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, this would achieve your goal:

```
n = 0
summed = 0
k = 1

while summed <= 100:
   n += 1
   summed = summed + k
   if summed <= 100:
       k = k + 2

print(f"Sum is: {summed}")
print(f"Last number: {k}") 
print(f"Loop count: {n}")
```

Answer (score -1):

This will solve your problem without changing your code too much:

```
n = int()
counter_sum = 0
counter = 0
k = 1
while counter_sum <= 100:  
  k+= 2
  counter_sum =counter_sum+ k
  counter+=1
print('Sum is:', counter_sum)
print("last number:", k) 
print("number of numbers added:", counter)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a loop for this. The sum of `1...n` with step size `k` is given by

```
s = ((n - 1) / k + 1) * (n + 1) / k
```

You can simplify this into a standard quadratic

```
s = (n**2 - k * n + k - 1) / k**2
```

To find integer solution for `s >= x`, solve `s = x` and take the ceiling of the result. Apply the quadratic formula to

```
n**2 - k * n + k - 1 = k**2 * x
```

The result is

```
n = 0.5 * (k + sqrt(k**2 - 4 * (k - k**2 * x - 1)))
```

For `k = 2`, `x = 100` you get:

```
>>> from math import ceil, sqrt
>>> k = 2
>>> x = 100
>>> n = 0.5 * (k + sqrt(k**2 - 4 * (k - k**2 * x - 1)))
>>> ceil(n)
21
```

The only complication arises when you get `n == ceil(n)`, since you actually want `s > x`. In that case, you can test:

```
c = ceil(n)
if n == c:
    c += 1
```

Comment: No loops solution - O(1) time and space complexity, just a formula - is the very right approach here. But we have `22` for `k = 2` and `x = 101`? I expected `last item = 21`, `number of items = 11`, `sum = 121`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko. I was wondering about that too. Wasn't handing the bounds correctly. Fixed now. It wouldn't take much to extend this to the general sum of a range.